# Java Web Start Error:access denied ("java.util.PropertyPermission" "*" "read,write")

Tags: java, security, java-web-start, jnlp

I am having some trouble running a Java Web Start application. It gives me below error:

```
java.security.AccessControlException: access denied
  ("java.util.PropertyPermission" "*" "read,write")     
    at java.security.AccessControlContext.checkPermission(Unknown Source)   
    at java.security.AccessController.checkPermission(Unknown Source)   
    at java.lang.SecurityManager.checkPermission(Unknown Source)    
    at com.sun.javaws.security.JavaWebStartSecurity.checkPermission(Unknown Source)     
    at java.lang.SecurityManager.checkPropertiesAccess(Unknown Source)  
    at java.lang.System.getProperties(Unknown Source)   
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.log.Log$1.run(Log.java:113)   
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)   
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.log.Log.<clinit>(Log.java:85)     
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.<clinit>(AbstractLifeCycle.java:35)
```

I use java 1.8.0_73. Jar files were properly signed by jarsigner. If I run my standalone jar then it is working fine. The same jar when I run from my JNLP file it gives me error.

My launch.jnlp is attached below

```java
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
    <jnlp codebase="file://C:/data"    href="launch.jnlp" spec="1.0+">
        <information>
            <title>WebStartSample</title>
            <vendor>user</vendor>
            <homepage href=""/>
            <description>WebStartSample</description>
            <description kind="short">WebStartSample</description>
        </information>
    <update check="always"/>
    <security>
        <all-permissions />
    </security>
    <resources>
        <j2se version="1.7+"/>
        <jar href="Sample.jar" main="true" />
        <extension name="Java Library" href="library.jnlp" />
    </resources>
        <application-desc main-class="webstartsample.Main">

        </application-desc>
    </jnlp>
```

Can anyone help me in resolving my issue? I tried adding permission in a Java policy file also but still same error. However I am looking for some suggestion where I do not want to make any change in policy file.

How to resolve this error?

```
#### Java Web Start Error:
#### access denied ("java.util.PropertyPermission" "*" "read,write")
```

Comment: Looks like you are using jetty.

Comment: @Johannes Kuhn Yes I am using jetty as Embedded Server

Comment: 1) *`codebase="file://C:/data"`* ***Why*** are you trying to launch this app. as though it were from the web, when it's a local app.? That might be complicating things. 2) Having said that, JWS is being deprecated, so I would not be pursuing it at all.

Comment: Have you tried something simple to check the basics. A single class application, that uses no further libraries, performing a security checked operation. (I find the Oracle tutorials useful for doing this sort of thing. Hopefully they are up to date. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/doingMoreWithRIA/security.html )